# Design Decision Django Rest Framework - Django as Frontend

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently developing my first more complex Web Application and want to ask for directions from more experienced Developers.

First I want to explain the most important requirements.

I want to develop a Web App (no mobile apps or desktop apps) and want to use as much django as possible. Because I am comfortable with the ecosystem right now and don't have that much time to learn something new that is too complex. I am inexperienced in the Javascript World, but I am able to do a little bit of jQuery.

The idea is to have one database and many different Frontends that are branded differently and have different users and administrators. So my current approach is to develop a Backend with Django and use Django Rest Framework to give the specific data to the Frontends via REST. Because I have not that much time to learn a Frontend-Framework I wanted to use another Django instance to use as a Frontend, as I really like the Django Template language. This would mean one Django instance one Frontend, where there would be mainly TemplateViews. The Frontends will be served on different subdomains, while the backend exposes the API Endpoints on the top level domain.

It is not necessary to have a Single Page App. A Normal Website with mainly the normal request/response-cycle is fine.

Do you think this is a possible approach to do things? I am currently thinking about how to use the data in the frontend sites in the best way. As I am familiar with the Django template language I thought about writing a middleware that asks about the user details in every request cycle from the backend. The thought is to use a request.user as normally as possible while getting the data from the backend.

Or is ist better to ask these details via jQuery and Ajax Calls and don't use the django template language very much?

Maybe there is also a way to make different Frontends for the same database without using REST?

Or what would you think about using a database with each frontend, which changes everytime I make a change in the main database in the backend? Although I don't really like this approach due to the possibility of differences in data if I make a mistake.

Hopefully this is not to confusing for you. If there are questions I will answer them happily. Maybe I am also totally on the wrong track. Please don't hesitate to point that out, too.

I thank you very much in advance for your guiding and wish you a nice day.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for your input om tripathi.

I think it really does make sense to use the modern js frameworks for consuming a REST API.

I looked a little further into my problem and found multitenancy to fit my requirements perfectly. There are also great plugins and good reads for that use case. Just for others some informations I stumbled upon:

https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/multi-tenancy/

https://www.vinta.com.br/blog/2017/multitenancy-juggling-customer-data-django/

Especially the second link gave me information about different design approaches. For myself I chose to go the way with one database for every Client and then using the site framework from django to seperate data. For the Subdomain resolving I use django-hosts.

Thank you again and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

as per my experience and knowledge, you are almost going towards correct direction.
my recommendation is for making backend rest api Django and django rest framework is the best option however for consuming those api you can look for the angular or react both works very well in terms of consuming API.